# Error 'Cannot redeclare ctools_menu_add_tab()' after migrating website

Tags: 6, routes, migrations, wysiwyg, chaos-tool-suite

After our hosting provider has migrated our website to a new server this fatal error occurs when accessing the site:

> **Fatal error**: Cannot redeclare ctools_menu_add_tab() (previously
>   declared in
>   /www/htdocs/mysite/drupal/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/menu.inc:42)
>   in
>   **/www/htdocs/mysite/drupal/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ctools/includes/menu.inc**
>   on line **49**

Now the mother of all questions: How can I fix this? :(

We're using Drupal 6 and – although I haven't checked it yet – all files and databases *should* have been copied correctly by our hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ctools installed twice, in:

- sites/all/modules/ctools
- sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ctools

Obviously the second path must have been mistake. If you can acces your page, disable ctools and then remove second instance. If you can't, try to do it using drush. If that fails, too, consider re-migration, this time properly. If all else fails, you may try to simply remove second instance and call update.php to perform some cleanup.

Comment: Unfortunately the error is on every page. So I guess I have to check out drush. But it's indeed very strange that ctools is *inside* the CKEditor module.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown Someone must have drag'n'dropped it by accident. Happens. Folders are like next to each other.

Comment: Are folders automatically scanned by Drupal? I'd have thought that they are ignored if not specifically referenced in the database.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown but when Drupal finds database inaccurate, like, after migration, it rescans automagically.

Comment: I've removed the duplicate directory and ran `update.php`. My site is now up again, but the panels aren't working. I'm sometimes getting the error message _The plugin definition of panels_layouts cannot locate schema panels_layout_.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown That's what you get for removing directory without disabling module. Disable ctools (and everything that depends on it, obviously, clear caches, `DELETE FROM {system} WHERE \`name\` LIKE '%ctools%'` and enable things again. Should help. Just don't forget to make a backup. Just in case. And switch to maintenance mode.

Comment: Another problem was that Panels doesn't support PHP 5.4.